# Pandas - aggregate, sort and nlargest inside groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
                       some_id
2016-12-26 11:03:10        001
2016-12-26 11:03:13        001
2016-12-26 12:03:13        001
2016-12-26 12:03:13        008
2016-12-27 11:03:10        009
2016-12-27 11:03:13        009
2016-12-27 12:03:13        003
2016-12-27 12:03:13        011
```

And i need to do something like transform('size') with following sort and get N max values.
To get something like this (N=2):

```
             some_id   size
2016-12-26       001      3
                 008      1
2016-12-27       009      2
                 003      1
```

Is there elegant way to do that in pandas 0.19.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to compute distinct counts after grouping on the `date` part of your `DateTimeIndex`. This sorts them in descending order by default.

You only need to take the topmost 2 rows of this result to get the largest (top-2) part.

```
fnc = lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2)
grp = df.groupby(df.index.date)['some_id'].apply(fnc).reset_index(1, name='size')
grp.rename(columns={'level_1':'some_id'})
```

[image]

Comment: It was my first idea, but i can't apply `head` or `nlargest` after value_counts.

Comment: Looks good. I think we can not to reset index.
Just `df.groupby(df.index.date)['some_id'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))`

Comment: Yeah, you could go without it. I assumed you wanted a `DF` back.

Answer (score 2):

***setup***

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """                 some_id
2016-12-26 11:03:10        001
2016-12-26 11:03:13        001
2016-12-26 12:03:13        001
2016-12-26 12:03:13        008
2016-12-27 11:03:10        009
2016-12-27 11:03:13        009
2016-12-27 12:03:13        003
2016-12-27 12:03:13        011"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.some_id = df.some_id.astype(str).str.zfill(3)

df

                    some_id
2016-12-26 11:03:10     001
2016-12-26 11:03:13     001
2016-12-26 12:03:13     001
2016-12-26 12:03:13     008
2016-12-27 11:03:10     009
2016-12-27 11:03:13     009
2016-12-27 12:03:13     003
2016-12-27 12:03:13     011
```

---

***using `nlargest`***

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).some_id.value_counts() \
    .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(2)

            some_id
2016-12-26  001        3
            008        1
2016-12-27  009        2
            003        1
Name: some_id, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in one line.

```
df.resample('D')['some_id'].apply(lambda s: s.value_counts().iloc[:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the `sizes` column, you can use the following.

```
df.groupby('some_id')['size'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).nlargest(2)
```

Otherwise, you could use this approach.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'some_id':[1,1,1,8,9,9,3,11],
                   'some_idx':[26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27]})

sizes = df.groupby(['some_id', 'some_idx']).size()

sizes.groupby(level='some_idx').nlargest(2)

# some_idx  some_id  some_idx
# 26        1        26          3
#           8        26          1
# 27        9        27          2
#           3        27          1
```

Comment: I think it's very close but i have no column 'size' and need to calculate it.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Edited to reflect this requirement. I think creating a new `groupby` object is the clearest for understanding.